# How do I insert a PHP variable inside of an HTML <a> tag?

Tags: php, html

This is my source code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$query = $_REQUEST["search"];

Print "<iframe src="http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$query"></iframe>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to have it where, when the user types in a term, then it automatically brings them to the Wikipedia page of their query.  I definitely know I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: You need to fix your quotes in the print statement.

Comment: You're mismatching your quotes, if the error you're having is a syntax error. Otherwise, Wikipedia might be configured to "bust out" of iframes.

Comment: I don't know if it wasn't implied enough, but I wanted to mention that $query is not the page I'm going to, but the actual query from the user's search itself.  All the answers given thus far have led my iframe to a literal Wikipedia page titled "$query", which isn't what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Same way you output any variable into HTML text content or attribute values, using `htmlspecialchars()`. If you don't do this every time you drop user data into HTML, you've got an HTML-injection vulnerability leading to cross-site-scripting (XSS) exploits.
2. In your case you are inserting a variable into a URL component, so before you HTML-encode, you need to URL-encode, using `rawurlencode()`.
3. OK... so if you're doing URL-encoding, you can actually skip the HTML-encoding if you want, because all characters that are special to HTML are also turned into safe `%` sequences by URL-encoding.
4. PHP is a templating language. Use it, don't fight it. Any time you `echo` or `print` an interpolated string from inside a PHP block, you're probably making life unnecessarily hard for yourself.

Include literal content verbatim and don't worry about backslash-escaping quote characters in string literals:

```
<?php
    $query= $_REQUEST['search'];
?>
<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<?php echo rawurlencode($query); ?>">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I'm removing my answer and +1 to this because it's the better answer with regards escaping

Answer (score 5):

Change your statement to:

```
print "<iframe src=\"http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$query\"></iframe>";
```

You needed to escape the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to include huge html strings inside print / echo statements, it makes it easy to make quoting mistakes and tough to follow what's going on with your code.

Instead you can include variables as tokens inside the html like many templating languages, but using the shorthand echo functionality `<?= $variable; ?>`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<?= $_REQUEST["search"]; ?>"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better to use `<?php echo $_REQUEST["search"]; ?>` because you're assuming short tags are turned on

Comment: its better if short tags are turned off yes lol, but irrelevant if they are on :)